# How can I make a time lapse video of my desktop

Tags: windows, timelapse

I would like to take a screenshot, every minute, of my screen, to create a time lapse video of my programming a game.

I found CamStudio, but it doesn't seem to have the option to simply save screenshots, not video.

Any ideas ?

I need a tool that would take a screenshot of the whole screen every minute, and automaticly save it somewhere.

Comment: wow, reading this gave me a Big Brother shiver.

Comment: Got a link to the finished video? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a cron job or shell script to take [screenshots](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=command+line+screen+capture) and then compile them into a movie file as Nifle suggested.
Could possibly use this as a shell script:

```
while true; do scrot -d 60; done
```

I'm not good at shell so someone could improve this

Answer (score 6):

There are several applications out there that does automatic screen captures, [AutoScreenShot](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Graphic/Graphic-Capture/AutoScreenShot.shtml) is one example.

Then when you have the images making a movie out of them is not *that* hard.

[Making movies from image files using ffmpeg/mencoder](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/)

Short version:

*We can also use ffmpeg directly to encode the images files into a movie. If we start with files name 001.jpg, 002.jpg, ..., we can use:*
`ffmpeg -r 10 -b 1800 -i %03d.jpg test1800.mp4`

Comment: No, it's the images I don't know how to take automaticly. :)

Comment: @Manu - Added link to screen capture software

Answer (score 5):

I came across a program Chronolapse, which might be useful for this :

http://code.google.com/p/chronolapse/

I didn't use it much myself, but it seems like it would do what you need, and it's free.

Comment: Seconding that recommendation for Chronolapse. It's very robust, reliable and free.